# Property access after animation

Tags: .net, wpf

I have animation code.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14"
                       Foreground="{Binding TextFill, Mode=OneWay}"
                       Text="{Binding Info, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       hlprs:AnimatableTextHelper.ProtectionProperty="{Binding ToogleButtonIsChecked, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="TextBlock_TargetUpdated"/>
```

TextBlock_TargetUpdated:

```
ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Green, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1300)));
                animation.Completed += (s, e_) =>
                {
                    tmpSender.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, null);

                    var b = tmpSender.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
                }; 
                animation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
                tmpSender.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
```

after the animation I can not update the property by binding and `b == null`.
I want the property to request the current value from dataconttext

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Declare the b variable outside of the animation and assign only assign it inside

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar, will it fix the binding?

Comment: I don't get what binding you are talking about, but it will keep the value assigned to the variable "b" even after the animation.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar, ok. I need update foreground after animation by binding, but it dosn't work.

Comment: Then you have to change the binding to TwoWay and once the animation is done, you set the TextFill property. Also ensure that you are notifying the UI after setting the TextFill property.